Why are some bars in the Time Machine timeline bar shorter than others?
I have set up Time Machine  and not always connect my Time Machine drive. So, my Mac does local snapshots from time to time. Sometimes these snapshots are not available.
If I want to click them in the Time Machine timeline bar on the right border of the screen the corresponding bar appears shorter than those that are clickable. Can't make a screenshot in Time Machine  unfortunately to show you.
What's wrong with those Time Machine  snapshots?

Preface: I wish I could find an actual Apple reference for this, but still believe that I understand this even without a direct reference from Apple.

Note: For reference, these observations are on macOS Sequoia 15.1.1 (24B91) using the latest APFS Time Machine setup.

I think the shorter bars are scheduled backups that haven’t changed significantly since a previous backup with a longer bar. Or the shorter bars are simply backups that are there but are somehow “not ready” yet.
I just triggered a manual Time Machine backup right now (8:09pm), right after a timed backup, and I see there are two backups dated “8:09pm”: One of them the long bar I can select and the other one a shorter bar I can’t select.
But then, as I was typing this — a few minutes later — I checked the Time Machine navigation again and now they are both long bars.
So my guess is there is some “housekeeping” that macOS needs to do before a backup becomes available for use. This seems to extend past the “Cleaning up…” task.
I think that with relatively “new” Time Machine drives, this task happens immediately. Then, after the Time Machine history has “aged” a bit, the “housekeeping” task takes slightly longer to happen.
PS: You can indeed take a screenshot in Time Machine if you hit Command+Shift+3. Apparently selective screenshots cannot be taken with Command+Shift+4.


Thanks for your answer. I am still not convinced this is the reason. I watched this over some days and the short bars seem to appear random. Even, if I check the same folder everytime I restard my Mac other backups are short and others are long. Haven't figured out a pattern yet.

In the end it might be connected to disk quotas. I was handling with some 20GB files. Today I coped some of those files from my backup not checking if I had enough space and ended up with a finder -36 exception (could not complete) and after that all locale snapshots were gone. Guess macOS was deleting local snapshots in the background to keep the system running.
